# How to change Bit Value to string in grid control

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

I'm trying to display data in devexpress grid control. I have a column called gender that takes bit values. I want to display the data that when its 1 the cell show Female and when its 0 the cell show male.

[image]

Comment: Show the code you use to put the data into the grid

Comment: @djv i added the data from the designer without using code.

Comment: Storing the data in the UI is a bad way to start. You should think about using a class to model your data then bind your UI to the class. See [this tutorial](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2389/common-features/data-binding/how-to-bind-a-control-to-data-created-at-runtime). You can then use code to manipulate the columns individually.

Comment: @YosraMhirig Did we ask to see the designer? No, we did not. We asked to see code. The designer view is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

just add columEditItem and set it to lookUpEdit.
Add in lookUpEdit two items the first with text male having a value true and the second with text female having a value false.
Set the column to readOnly
So,whenever the value is true it will shows male and same for female on false

hope this helps you.
feel free to ask any question